# Android Uber SDK Ride Estimate Returns Null Value

Tags: android, uber-api

I have been integrating Uber SDK with My Application and i am trying to get uber ride estimate with following code,

```
  RidesService service = UberRidesApi.with(session).build().createService();
                Response<ProductsResponse> response = service.getProducts((float) currentLatLng.latitude, (float) currentLatLng.longitude).execute();
                List<Product> products = response.body().getProducts();
                rideDetails.setProducts((ArrayList<Product>) products);
                if (products != null && products.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
                        Product product = products.get(i);
                        String productId = product.getProductId();
                        RideRequestParameters rideRequestParameters = new RideRequestParameters.Builder().setPickupCoordinates((float) currentLatLng.latitude, (float) currentLatLng.longitude)
                                .setProductId(productId)
                                .setDropoffCoordinates((float) mDestinationLatitude, (float) mDestinationLongitude)
                                .build();
                        RideEstimate rideEstimate = service.estimateRide(rideRequestParameters).execute().body();
                    }

                }
```

with this lines of code i am able to get the RideEstimate data's if the Native UBER app is not available but if its available i am getting the RideEstimate data as NULL. Please let me know if you could hel me in this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe create an issue in the Uber rides repo on GitHub here: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk? It's better place to report library specific issues than SO because you can get direct feedback from the authors of this project. I think there may be a bug in the library or you may use it in a wrong way.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen Thanks for the response. Let me try that.

Comment: for the record, ticket is here: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/issues/64